# Looping a Split over Lists

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am new to Python and I cannot seem to fix my error with any amount of Googling. I want to split a list using a loop, but cannot get the syntax correct.

```
alist = ["aa-aa-aa-aa|bb|cc","bb-bb-bb|abc|ab","cc-cccc-cc|abc|a"]
alist[0] = alist[0].split("|")
alist[0][0] = alist[0][0].split("-")
print(alist)
```

The above works for the case of splitting the first entry of the first entry, but I would like to split the first entry of each item in the list.

Given output :

```
[[['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'bb', 'cc'], 'bb-bb-bb|abc|ab', 'cc-cccc-cc|abc|a']
```

Desired output :

```
[[['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'bb', 'cc'], [['bb','bb','bb'],'abc','ab'], [['cc','cccc','cc'],'abc','a']
```

However when I try to loop like I would for a file I get an error.

```
alist = ["aa-aa-aa-aa|bb|cc","bb-bb-bb|abc|ab","cc-cccc-cc|abc|a"]
n = 0
for n in alist:
    alist[n] = alist[n].split("|")
    alist[n][0] = alist[n][0].split("-")
print(alist)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\EALDEN3\Documents\Python Code\Scratch.py", line 5, in <module>
    alist[n] = alist[n].split("|")
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a your `for` loop `n` is the element not the index, you need to do the loop differently if you want to work with indices:

```
alist = ["aa-aa-aa-aa|bb|cc","bb-bb-bb|abc|ab","cc-cccc-cc|abc|a"]
for index in range(len(alist)):
    alist[index] = alist[index].split("|")
    alist[index][0] = alist[index][0].split("-")
print(alist)
```

**Output:**

```
[[['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'bb', 'cc'], [['bb', 'bb', 'bb'], 'abc', 'ab'], [['cc', 'cccc','cc'], 'abc', 'a']]
```

Note that your solution does the operation in place (which is maybe not what you want).

If you want a one-liner this will also get the same output in an efficient manner:

```
result = [[val.split('-') if index == 0 else val for index, val in enumerate(substr.split('|'))] for substr in alist]
```

Comment: Why would I not want to do the operation in place?

Comment: Depends your use case. Some times you want to do something inplace, other times you want to not touch the original input. So its just user preference. I just wanted to make sure you recognize that with that solution, `alist` will change.

Comment: Got it. You were calling out that I was overwriting my original list instead of creating a new one. (I'm working on improving my lingo knowledge)

Comment: Quick Question: You say that the one liner code is more efficient. Do you mean space wise or does it actually process the data more efficiently? (Other 'new' users will be using my code and I am leaning toward readability a bit over efficiency.)

Comment: @EmilyAlden I meant more efficient than the other one-liner answers (it will be close to the efficiency of your current answer). I would highly recommend sticking with the code you got (readability counts).  Someone who knows a lot of python won't have much trouble reading advanced list comprehension but it is definitely not fun to read  for beginners or novices :). (Especially that nasty of a list comprehension).

Answer (score 2):

You can try a nested list comprehension for this :

```
alist = ["aa-aa-aa-aa|bb|cc","bb-bb-bb|abc|ab","cc-cccc-cc|abc|a"]
alist = [[j.split('-')  if j.count('-')>0 else j for j in i.split('|')] for i in alist]
```

**Output** :

```
[[['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'bb', 'cc'], [['bb', 'bb', 'bb'], 'abc', 'ab'], [['cc', 'cccc', 'cc'], 'abc', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fixed] I like list comprehensions and I think this will work:

```
alist = ["aa-aa-aa-aa|bb|cc","bb-bb-bb|abc|ab","cc-cccc-cc|abc|a"]

output = [[y.split('-') if '-' in y else y for y in x.split('|')] for x in alist]
print(output)
```

This is just a loop over each element in the original list, then split on the '|' and then split on '-' if '-' is in the substring.

The output is:

```
[[['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'aa'], 'bb', 'cc'], [['bb', 'bb', 'bb'], 'abc', 'ab'], [['cc', 'cccc', 'cc'], 'abc', 'a']]
```

Comment: This does not match the desired output.

Comment: argh, oops. standby

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse - should be fixed now... not quite as short....

Comment: Nice. Though just so you know the `in` call means you will go through it twice (once [or just partially] to look for `-` and another to do the actual `split`, plus you do it for each entry not just the first). My solution is more bug prone (because it assumes the first element in the `list` will be split by `-`) than yours though and mine will only ever split the first field. So this is just another valid solution :). (Yours is faster than the other answer though).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse True on the `in`, but given the type of algorithm I don't think `in` is actually going to do a check on every single character. I *think* it just stops when it finds the first match.  (But I don't have documentation to backup my thought).  I **think** `in` should be more efficient than a `count` operation because `in` is going for existence. (??)

Comment: Correct `in` is more efficient than `count` because it short circuits. (thats why your answer is faster than the other one).

Answer (score 0):

```
[ [x.split('|')[0].split('-')]+ x.split('|')[1:] for x in alist]
```

the above works, however split('|') will be called twice per item in alist